# How to equate hit probabilties on 2 different surfaces

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I'm looking for help in determining how to equate the following:

1. We have a surface of 13 cm X 10 cm.
2. We have a 95% probability of hit
   on a 16 cm diameter surface.

I would like to equate $B$, probability of hit to the 13cm X 10 cm surface. 95% probability of hit on a circle of 16 cm represent what probability of hit on the rectangle of 13cm X 10cm.

What is the mathematical steps to arrive to the solution?
It is a job related problem not a school one.

Comment: What's a "hit"?  Are you making an analogy to throwing darts at a dartboard?  If so, you need additional information (or equivalent strong assumptions) to get an answer: you need to know the statistical distribution of "hits" around a target's center.

Comment: Hi Whuber, a better analogy would be to go to the firing range and shoot for fun.  So 95% probability of hit represent 1.96 sigma S.D.  And the bullet is able to fly and hit the paper target with a precision or dispersion that would put all of the bullet in a 45 mm diameter. But the shooter with this quality of gun/bullet system need to be able to hit the target 95% of the time.

Comment: OK.  But precisely how is the 13 $\times$ 10 surface related to the target?  At what point is the shooter aiming?  And what distinction are you trying to make between darts and bullets: aren't they essentially the same physical analogy?

Comment: As for the darts or the bullets analogy it is ok... Yes they are the same but I thought that it would be clearer or more easy to explain.                                                **The Point of Aim is the centre of the target**  The 13*10 (130 cm^2) surface is the new target.  In one case, I have a 95% probability of hit on a circular surface of 16 cm diametre (201 cm^2). How does this translate in probability of hitting the 130 cm^2 target?       p.s. thanks for the help in any cases

Answer (score 4):

**If we assume the distribution of hits is binormal**, then the distribution of the distance to the center of the target is a scaled [Chi distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) with two degrees of freedom.  From this (applying its inverse CDF), we find that its 95th percentile coincides with the radius of 16/2 = 8 centimeters when the scaling factor equals 1.33523.  This factor is also the standard deviation of the components of the binormal distribution.  Integrating the PDF of that binormal distribution over a 13 by 10 cm rectangle centered at the point of aim gives 0.83311, the desired value of $B$.

Here's a picture showing a shaded contour plot of the PDF restricted to that rectangle, with the circular target behind it for reference:

[image: Target]

The value of 0.83311 was found with *Mathematica*:

```
With[{s = 8 / InverseCDF[ChiDistribution[2], 0.95]}, 
 NIntegrate[PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0,0},{s,s},0],{x,y}], {x,-13/2,13/2}, {y,-10/2,10/2}]
]
```

It was checked by simulating 100,000 independent shots and reporting the proportions that (a) fell within the 16 cm circular target and (b) fell within the rectangular target:

```
With[{s = 8 / InverseCDF[g, 0.95], n = 100000}, 
 data = RandomReal[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {s, s}, 0], n];
 old = Length[Select[data, Norm[#] <= 8 &]] / n;
 new = Length[Select[data, Abs[#[[1]]] <= 13/2 && Abs[#[[2]]] <= 10/2 &]] / n;
 {old, new} // N
]
```

The output of `{0.94919, 0.83331}` is close enough to the intended values of `{0.95, 0.83311}` to confirm the correctness of the calculations.

Comment: Whuber,  Thank you very much for this.  I cannot clainm to understand everthing.  But I'll make special diligence to understand this.

Comment: WHuber, Together with a co-worker, we have understood your approach and solution... thanks